# efficient method of downloading webpage info

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

Before you stop reading and suggest HTML Agility (based on the title), I am already using this tool. The problem is this: I have have a webpage that lists a whole bunch of case numbers and has links to the individual case number page. My app already downloads this info and displays it in a `datagridview`. However in my app I also need information from the individual case number pages (the links).

The problem is I already know it's going to take forever to acquire using HTML agility. To get the case page, it takes about 2 minutes. Code wise I'm feeding HTML agility the HTML code, adding the cell values to an array and parsing out the array indexes I to display in my grid. This is a very large array parse for the number of components on the page.

Any ideas to acquire the main page and specific cells from the linked pages?

Comment: if you are using Html Agility pack then why not use xpath to just get the element types you want. I am happy to give you an example if you show me some html and what you want out of it

Comment: yes if you have any example that would be handy. I have not experimented with xpath. Only `HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode cell in row.SelectNodes("td")` which returns many, many cells.

Comment: _"Any ideas to acquire [..] specific cells from the linked pages?"_ - You'll have to download all of the HTML in order to be able to parse it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example showing how you can use XPath in HmtlAgility

> HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument(); doc.LoadHtml(yourHtml);
>
> **Example 1 :** //The below example will get all div's with class as container foreach (HtmlNode node in
>   doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='container']")) {
>   Console.Writeline(node.InnerText); }
>
> **Example 2 :** //The below example will get first div with class as container HtmlNode node in
>   doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='container'][1]"))
>
> Console.Writeline(node.InnerText);

You can use Xpath Queries to get the element(s) you want

for XPath syntax and more please use the link http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp